# Iterating through Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, google-maps, pandas

I'm iterating through a pandas dataframe and hoping to add values to one of the columns row-by-row.

My task is geocoding a set of addresses using a geocoder package - http://geocoder.readthedocs.io/

geocoder.google(X).latlng returns a tuple with 2 values -> (x,y)

I want to be able to add both the x & y values to specific columns in dataframe. I know that tuples are imutable, but can I not iterate through every row & add data? If not, how can I add these values whilst keeping a 2 second delay between loops?

```
RS1995 = pd.read_csv("RSM100_1995.csv",header=None)

RS1995.columns = ['ID','Price','Date','Postcode','X','Y','Z','PAON','SAON','Street','Locality','District','City','County','A','B','Address','XX']
print(RS1995.head())

RS1995['lat'] = "x"   #Adding column for latitude coordinates
RS1995['lng'] = "y"   #Adding column for longitude coordinates

for row in RS1995.iterrows():
    g = geocoder.google(str(row[1][17])) 
    print("X Value is: "+g.latlng[0])   #I've tested this, and it does print values
    print("Y Value is: "+g.latlng[1])
    row[19] = g.latlng[0]
    row[20] = g.latlng[1]
    time.sleep(2)  #There is a rate limit with Google's Geocoder so adding 2 second wait
```

Comment: you don't need to iterate, just add the columns as `df = df.assign(<colname>=<array_of_values>`)

Comment: How would ensure that the rate limit isn't breached? How would I do 1 geocode a second?

Comment: All I'm saying is that you need to precompute your x, y values before inserting them into your dataframe. If your main issue is throttling your iterations, there is a ton of information about that already on SO.